# QFile copy - static vs temporary object

Tags: c++, qt, copy, qfile

Next two strings of Qt C++ code do the same stuff and without any problems to me.

```
QFile(source).copy(destination); 
QFile::copy(source, destination);
```

The question is about performance of first and second. Does code of Qt optimised inside static method and doesn't it create two objects? Which one is better and etc.

Comment: Why didn't you simply measure runtime?

Comment: Or look into the sources yourself?

Comment: I prefer the first version because you can get details when it fails, via errorString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Qt 5.5.1:

```
bool  QFile::copy(const QString &fileName, const QString &newName)
{
    return QFile(fileName).copy(newName);
}
```

Hope that give's you an idea =)